# mqtt integration with java

Tags: java, mqtt

I want to integrate Mqtt program with java Code.The following is my java code to which i need to send message to the device through MQTT broker connection....So,that i need to send message eg: 3G SETT;56:1024; to the device while connecting through mqtt broker.so i need to call the mqtt connection method into the program...

Tell me where exactly write and edit the code and where to integrate the mqtt broker code

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class message implements MqttCallback
{

    static int option;
    static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    static boolean go = true; // for starting main outer loop
    static boolean run = true;
    static String ip;
    static String entire_address,topic;
    static int port;
    static String apn;
    static String msg;



static void operator_apn() {

        System.out.println("Enter operator APN");
        apn = sc.next();
        msg = "3gc SETT;" + 0 + 1 + ":" + apn + ";";
        System.out.println("Your message Format is:" + msg);


        System.out.println("Enter Topic Name");
        topic=sc.next();
        System.out.println("Enter Modem Ip address");
        ip=sc.next();
        System.out.println("Enter Modem Port Number");
        port=sc.nextInt();
        entire_address=ip+":"+port;
        System.out.print("Entire Address is:"+entire_address);

    }

    static void apn_user_id() {
        String username, msg;
        System.out.println("Enter APN UserName");
        username = sc.next();
        msg = "3gc SETT;" + 0 + 2 + ":" + username + ";";
        System.out.println("Your APN UserName Format is:" + msg);
    }

    static void apn_user_password() {
        String password, msg;
        System.out.println("Enter APN Password");
        password = sc.next();
        msg = "3gc SETT;" + 0 + 3 + ":" + password + ";";
        System.out.println("Your APN Password Format is:" + msg);
    }

    static void primary_server_ip() {
        String ip, msg;
        System.out.println("Enter Server primary ip");
        ip = sc.next();
        msg = "3gc SETT;" + 4 + ":" + ip + ";";
        System.out.println("Your Primary Server ip Format is:" + msg);
    }

    static void primary_server_port() {
        String msg;
        int port;
        System.out.println("Enter Primary server port");
        port = sc.nextInt();
        msg = "3g SETT;" + 5 + ":" + port + ";";
        System.out.println("Your Primary Server port Format is:" + msg);
    }

    static void secondary_server_ip() {
        String ip, msg;
        System.out.println("Enter Server secondary ip");
        ip = sc.next();
        msg = "3gc SETT;" + 6 + ":" + ip + ";";
        System.out.println("Your Secondary Server ip Format is:" + msg);
    }

    static void secondary_server_port() {
        String msg;
        int port;
        System.out.println("Enter Secondary server port");
        port = sc.nextInt();
        msg = "3g SETT;" + 7 + ":" + port + ";";
        System.out.println("Your Secondary Server port Format is:" + msg);
    }

    static void fota_apn() {
        String apn, msg;
        System.out.println("Enter FOTA APN");
        apn = sc.next();
        msg = "3gc SETT;" + 8 + ":" + apn + ";";
        System.out.println("Your FOTA APN Format is:" + msg);
    }

    static void fota_server_ip() {
        String ip, msg;
        System.out.println("Enter FOTA Server ip");
        ip = sc.next();
        msg = "3gc SETT;" + 9 + ":" + ip + ";";
        System.out.println("Your FOTA Server ip Format is:" + msg);
    }

    static void fota_server_port() {
        String msg;
        int port;
        System.out.println("Enter FOTA server port");
        port = sc.nextInt();
        msg = "3g SETT;" + 10 + ":" + port + ";";
        System.out.println("Your FOTA Server port Format is:" + msg);
    }

    static void connection_retry_time() {
        String msg;
        int time;
        System.out.println("Enter Connection Retry Time");
        time = sc.nextInt();
        msg = "3g SETT;" + 11 + ":" + time + ";";
        System.out.println("Your Connection Retry Time Format is:" + msg);
    }

    static void keep_alive_time() {
        String msg;
        int time;
        System.out.println("Enter Keep Alive Time");
        time = sc.nextInt();
        msg = "3g SETT;" + 12 + ":" + time + ";";
        System.out.println("Your Keep Alive Time Format is:" + msg);
    }

    static void mp_size() {
        String msg;
        int size;
        System.out.println("Enter MP Size");
        size = sc.nextInt();
        msg = "3g SETT;" + 13 + ":" + size + ";";
        System.out.println("Your MP Size Format is:" + msg);
    }

    static void mh_size() {
        String msg;
        int size;
        System.out.println("Enter MH Size");
        size = sc.nextInt();
        msg = "3g SETT;" + 14 + ":" + size + ";";
        System.out.println("Your MH Size Format is:" + msg);
    }

    static void message_queing_username() {
        String username, msg;
        System.out.println("Enter Message Queing UserName");
        username = sc.next();
        msg = "3gc SETT;" + 22 + ":" + username + ";";
        System.out.println("Your Message Queing UserName Format is:" + msg);
    }

    static void message_queing_password() {
        String password, msg;
        System.out.println("Enter Message Queing password");
        password = sc.next();
        msg = "3gc SETT;" + 23 + ":" + password + ";";
        System.out.println("Your Message Queing password Format is:" + msg);
    }

    static void data_center_smsc_number() {
        long number;
        String msg;
        System.out.println("Enter Data Center SMSC Mobile Number");
        number = sc.nextLong();
        msg = "3gc SETT;" + 24 + ":" + number + ";";
        System.out.println("Your Data Center SMSC Mobile Number Format is:"
                + msg);
    }

    static void application_instant_time() {
        String msg;
        int time;
        System.out.println("Enter Application Instant Time");
        time = sc.nextInt();
        msg = "3g SETT;" + 51 + ":" + time + ";";
        System.out.println("Your Application Instant Time Setting Format is:"
                + msg);
    }

    static void app_billing_time() {
        String msg;
        int time;
        System.out.println("Enter Application Billing Time");
        time = sc.nextInt();
        msg = "3g SETT;" + 52 + ":" + time + ";";
        System.out.println("Your Application Billing Time Setting Format is:"
                + msg);
    }

    static void app_load_time() {
        String msg;
        int time;
        System.out.println("Enter Application Load Time");
        time = sc.nextInt();
        msg = "3g SETT;" + 53 + ":" + time + ";";
        System.out.println("Your Application Load Time Setting Format is:"
                + msg);
    }

    static void app_event_time() {
        String msg;
        int time;
        System.out.println("Enter Application Event Time");
        time = sc.nextInt();
        msg = "3g SETT;" + 54 + ":" + time + ";";
        System.out.println("Your Application Event Time Setting Format is:"
                + msg);
    }

    static void identify_time() {
        String msg;
        int time;
        System.out.println("Enter Identify Time");
        time = sc.nextInt();
        msg = "3g SETT;" + 55 + ":" + time + ";";
        System.out.println("Your Identifyt Time Setting Format is:" + msg);
    }

    static void app_identify_log() {
        String msg;
        int log;
        System.out.println("Enter Application Identify Log");
        log = sc.nextInt();
        msg = "3g SETT;" + 56 + ":" + log + ";";
        System.out.println("Your Application Identify Log Format is:" + msg);
    }

    static void app_instant_log() {
        String msg;
        int log;
        System.out.println("Enter Application Instant log");
        log = sc.nextInt();
        msg = "3g SETT;" + 57 + ":" + log + ";";
        System.out.println("Your Application Instant log Setting Format is:"
                + msg);
    }

    static void app_bill_log() {
        String msg;
        int log;
        System.out.println("Enter Application Bill Log");
        log = sc.nextInt();
        msg = "3g SETT;" + 58 + ":" + log + ";";
        System.out.println("Your Application Instant Bill Log Format is:" + msg);
    }

    static void app_load_log() {
        String msg;
        int log;
        System.out.println("Enter Application Load Log");
        log = sc.nextInt();
        msg = "3g SETT;" + 59 + ":" + log + ";";
        System.out.println("Your Application Load Log Format is:" + msg);
    }

    static void app_event_log() {
        String msg;
        int log;
        System.out.println("Enter Application Event Log");
        log = sc.nextInt();
        msg = "3g SETT;" + 60 + ":" + log + ";";
        System.out.println("Your Application Event Log Format is:" + msg);
    }

    static void load_survey_days() {
        String msg;
        int days;
        System.out.println("Enter Load Survey Days");
        days = sc.nextInt();
        msg = "3g SETT;" + 61 + ":" + days + ";";
        System.out.println("Your Load Survey Days Format is:" + msg);
    }

    static void schedule_interval() {
        String msg;
        int interval;
        System.out.println("Enter Schedule Interval");
        interval = sc.nextInt();
        msg = "3g SETT;" + 62 + ":" + interval + ";";
        System.out.println("Your Schedule Interval Format is:" + msg);
    }

    static void dlms_password() {
        String password, msg;
        System.out.println("Enter DLMS Password");
        password = sc.next();
        msg = "3g SETT;" + 63 + ":" + password + ";";
        System.out.println("Your DLMS Password Format is:" + msg);

    }

    static void dia_time() {
        int time;
        String msg;
        System.out.println("Enter DIA Time");
        time = sc.nextInt();
        msg = "3g SETT;" + 64 + ":" + time + ";";
        System.out.println("Your DIA Time Format is:" + msg);

    }

    static void dia_sample() {
        int sample;
        String msg;
        System.out.println("Enter DIA Sample");
        sample = sc.nextInt();
        msg = "3g SETT;" + 65 + ":" + sample + ";";
        System.out.println("Your DIA Time Sample is:" + msg);

    }

    static void schedule_enable() {
        int schedule;
        String msg;
        System.out.println("Enter Schedule Enable");
        schedule = sc.nextInt();
        msg = "3g SETT;" + 66 + ":" + schedule + ";";
        System.out.println("Your Schedule Enable Format is:" + msg);

    }

    static void schedule_hour() {
        int time;
        String msg;
        System.out.println("Enter Schedule Hour");
        time = sc.nextInt();
        msg = "3g SETT;" + 67 + ":" + time + ";";
        System.out.println("Your Schedule Hour Format is:" + msg);

    }

    static void schedule_mins() {
        int time;
        String msg;
        System.out.println("Enter Schedule Mins");
        time = sc.nextInt();
        msg = "3g SETT;" + 68 + ":" + time + ";";
        System.out.println("Your Schedule Mins Format is:" + msg);

    }

    static void event_order_request() {
        int order_request;
        String msg;
        System.out.println("Enter Event Order Request");
        order_request = sc.nextInt();
        msg = "3g SETT;" + 69 + ":" + order_request + ";";
        System.out.println("Your Event Order request Format is:" + msg);

    }

    static void event_fifo() {
        int fifo;
        String msg;
        System.out.println("Enter Event FIFO");
        fifo = sc.nextInt();
        msg = "3g SETT;" + 70 + ":" + fifo + ";";
        System.out.println("Your Event FIFO Format is:" + msg);

    }

    static void app_send_load_select() {
        int load;
        String msg;
        System.out.println("Enter App Send Load Select");
        load = sc.nextInt();
        msg = "3g SETT;" + 71 + ":" + load + ";";
        System.out.println("Your App Send Load Select Format is:" + msg);
    }







    public static void main(String[] args) throws MqttException {

        while (go == true) {
            while (run == true) {

                System.out.println("\n 1.Enter operator APN \n 2.Enter APN userId \n 3.Enter APN password \n 4.Enter primary server ip \n 5.Enter primary server port \n"
                                + " 6.Enter Secondary Server IP \n 7.Enter Secondary Server Port \n 8.Enter FOTA APN \n 9.Enter FOTA Server IP \n 10.Enter FOTA server Port \n"
                                + " 11.Enter Connection Retry Time \n 12.Enter Keep Alive Time \n 13.Enter MP Size \n 14.Enter MH Size \n"
                                + " 15.Enter Message Queing UserName \n 16.Enter Message Queing Password \n 17.Enter Data Center SMSC Number \n 18.Enter App Instant Time \n"
                                + " 19.Enter App Billing Time \n 20.Enter App Load Time \n 21.Enter App Event Time \n 22.Enter Identify Time \n 23.Enter App Identify Log \n"
                                + " 24.Enter App Instant Time \n 25.Enter App Bill Log \n 26.Enter App Load Log \n 27.Enter App Event Log \n 28.Enter Load Survey Days \n"
                                + " 29.Enter Schedule Interval \n 30.Enter DLMS Password \n 31.Enter DIA Time \n 32.Enter DIA Sample \n 33.Enter Schedule Enable \n"
                                + " 34.Enter Schedule Hour \n 35.Enter Schedule Mins \n 36.Enter Event Order Request \n 37.Enter Event FIFO \n 38.Enter App Send Load Select \n"
                                + " 39.Change Meter \n 40.Restart Meter ");

                System.out.println("Enter your option:");
                option = sc.nextInt();

                switch (option) {
                case 1:
                    operator_apn();
                    sendMessage();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    apn_user_id();
                    message.sendMessage();
                    break;
                case 3:
                    apn_user_password();
                    message.sendMessage();
                    break;
                case 4:
                    primary_server_ip();
                    message.sendMessage();
                    break;
                case 5:
                    primary_server_port();
                    message.sendMessage();
                    break;
                case 6:
                    secondary_server_ip();
                    message.sendMessage();
                    break;
                case 7:
                    secondary_server_port();
                    message.sendMessage();
                    break;
                case 8:
                    fota_apn();
                    message.sendMessage();
                    break;
                case 9:
                    fota_server_ip();
                    message.sendMessage();
                    break;
                case 10:
                    fota_server_port();
                    message.sendMessage();
                    break;
                case 11:
                    connection_retry_time();
                    message.sendMessage();
                    break;
                case 12:
                    keep_alive_time();
                    message.sendMessage();
                    break;
                case 13:
                    mp_size();
                    message.sendMessage();
                    break;
                case 14:
                    mh_size();
                    message.sendMessage();
                    break;
                case 15:
                    message_queing_username();
                    message.sendMessage();
                    break;
                case 16:
                    message_queing_password();
                    message.sendMessage();
                    break;
                case 17:
                    data_center_smsc_number();
                    message.sendMessage();
                    break;
                case 18:
                    application_instant_time();
                    message.sendMessage();
                    break;
                case 19:
                    app_billing_time();
                    message.sendMessage();
                    break;
                case 20:
                    app_load_time();
                    message.sendMessage();
                    break;
                case 21:
                    app_event_time();
                    message.sendMessage();
                    break;
                case 22:
                    identify_time();
                    message.sendMessage();
                    break;
                case 23:
                    app_identify_log();
                    message.sendMessage();
                    break;
                case 24:
                    app_instant_log();
                    message.sendMessage();
                    break;
                case 25:
                    app_bill_log();
                    message.sendMessage();
                    break;
                case 26:
                    app_load_log();
                    message.sendMessage();
                    break;
                case 27:
                    app_event_log();
                    message.sendMessage();
                    break;
                case 28:
                    load_survey_days();
                    message.sendMessage();
                    break;
                case 29:
                    schedule_interval();
                    message.sendMessage();
                    break;
                case 30:
                    dlms_password();
                    message.sendMessage();
                    break;
                case 31:
                    dia_time();message.sendMessage();
                    break;
                case 32:
                    dia_sample();
                    message.sendMessage();
                    break;
                case 33:
                    schedule_enable();
                    message.sendMessage();
                    break;
                case 34:
                    schedule_hour();
                    message.sendMessage();
                    break;
                case 35:
                    schedule_mins();
                    message.sendMessage();
                    break;
                case 36:
                    event_order_request();
                    message.sendMessage();
                    break;
                case 37:
                    event_fifo();
                    message.sendMessage();
                    break;
                case 38:
                    app_send_load_select();
                    message.sendMessage();
                    break;
                case 39:
                    System.out.println("Change Meter");
                    break;
                case 40:
                    System.out.println("Restart");
                    break;

                default:
                    System.err.println("Invalid Option");

                }

                run = false;
            }

            if (run == false) {
                System.out.println("\nWould you like to run again? Y/N");
                char again = sc.next().charAt(0);
                again = Character.toUpperCase(again);
                if (again == 'Y') {
                    run = true;
                } else if (again == 'N') {
                    System.out.println("Exit.");
                    go = false;
                } else {
                    System.err.println("Invalid entry. Try again.");
                }
            }
```

Comment: Which MQTT Implementation are you using? There is [Eclipse Paho Java Client](https://eclipse.org/paho/clients/java/) which I used recently which has a very nice API.

Comment: As @Ischuetze mentioned, pls check the sample code of Paho firstly.

Comment: And what is the issue? Offtopic: A class name that starts with a lower case character is not really correct by the standards

Comment: Actually the task is, I need to send,FIBOCOM Module settings to device,which is connected in field, while connecting through MQTT broker as per the above code(Once read the above code and you will get some idea!!) and i need to integrate above java code to MQTT Eclipse paho code.

Answer (score 2):

Using the **Java Paho MQTT Library** you should look at the examples to understand how to implement a client that publishes to an MQTT Broker.

Normally first you should implement the method `.connect` to a Broker, and after that you use the method `.publish` to send a message containing a `payload` to an specific `topic` into the MQTT Broker.

You should look at the [sample Paho app](http://git.eclipse.org/c/paho/org.eclipse.paho.mqtt.java.git/tree/org.eclipse.paho.sample.mqttv3app/src/main/java/org/eclipse/paho/sample/mqttv3app).

And also to the implemented [Paho client tests](http://git.eclipse.org/c/paho/org.eclipse.paho.mqtt.java.git/tree/org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.test/src/test/java/org/eclipse/paho/client/mqttv3/test).

Answer (score -1):

The MQTT messages can be send with the help of a broker. Here the broker can be anything which have the implementation of MQTT protocol. As of now, the versions is 3.1.1

To send the messages over MQTT, you need to have a Paho library, It is available in different flavours. The once I used was eclipse Paho Library.

Given below are two links through which you can implement.

1. Eclipse Paho implementation example: https://www.hivemq.com/blog/mqtt-client-library-encyclopedia-eclipse-paho-java
2. Online MQTT broker for testing (HiveMQ): https://www.hivemq.com/try-out/
3. Online MQTT broker Dashboard (HiveMQ): http://www.mqtt-dashboard.com/

Comment: This does not answer the question, it's just a list of links